# Trying to integrate builder.io pages with Angular for preview URL hosting in localhost

Tags: angular, builder.io

im building the webpage in builder.io, so i want to preview my content which build in that, so to preview i have to integrate my page model with some external site or app where i want to preview so As shown in the documentation (https://www.builder.io/c/docs/integrating-builder-pages#create-an-app-if-you-dont-have-one) i selected the localhost so and my frame work is angular And i followed all steps mentioned in the documentation, and my local host was running successfully(http://localhost:4200/). After connected my local host with my page model the content that build in visual editor is not loading as shown in below images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkU5b.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEYNv.jpg). And also even i try preview by clicking eye ball icon in view current draft to preview my app or site by hosting the localhost it load the default HTML code in app.component.html.

I build some content in visual editor, so I wanted to preview that content in localhost. I have successfully run the localhost by following Documentation Integrating pages and I used Angular as my frame work. After connected my localhost to my builder pages the content in visual editor is not loading.
As i was a fresher in coding I tried to set the connection in source code to get preview the Content which i build in builder.io it didn't work!.

My page URL
https://builder.io/content/c41549a4761d4770be34a2a22f6d7d42

My public API: 5ea6536bfd704e43a620fd82d7b0dad0

I’d like to preview my webpage in the visual editor on localhost.